# How to use implicit casting when accessing members?

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

I have a Wraper class that has a field holding a reference to the object I want to cast to
(constructers omitted for clearness)

```cs
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    private T inner;
    public static implicit operator T(Wrapper<T> w) => w.inner;
}

public class InnerClass{
    public void say(){
        Console.Writeline("hey");
    }
}
```

and in another class I want to access the wrapped member directly

```cs
public class Other
{
    private Wrapper<InnerClass> item;
    void func(){
        item.say();// ERROR: Cannot resolve symbol 'say()'
    }
}
```

explicit casting works but it is too clunky for my use as the wrapper class only provides null guarantee and I need it to work with other code that expects InnerClass

```cs
public class Other
{
    private Wrapper<InnerClass> item;
    void func(){
        ((InnerClass)item).say();// this works
    }
}
```

what is the best way to go about doing this? (without explicit casting)

actual implementation below(it is unity code)

```cs
public class AutoFind<T> where T:MonoBehaviour
    {
        private T x
        {
            get
            {
                if (!_x)
                {
                    _x = Object.FindObjectOfType<T>();
                }
                return _x;
            }
        }

        private T _x;
        public static implicit operator T(AutoFind<T> t) => t.x;
    }
```

Comment: For an implicit cast you'd do something like `InnerClass x = item;` and then`x.say()`.   Implicit casting is only done during assignment or when passed to a method, it isn't done to try to resolve methods.

Comment: @juharr The problem with doing it this way is that `T x` can change between calls and I need to always access the latest one. afaik `InnerClass x = item` would always point to the same `T x` whatever it was at the time of assignment

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use Raw

```
 public class Wrapper<T>
    {
        private T inner;
        public static implicit operator T(Wrapper<T> w) => w.inner;

        public T Raw
        {
            get
            {
                return inner;
            }
        }
    }
```

and after

```
item.Raw.say();
```

Comment: While it seems like this is what I am going to do, I was looking for a way to do this without refactoring all the usages of many `InnerClass`es.

Comment: When you find wahy, please share, I got curious now